# Jquery mobile event when the user moves away from the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I want an event to be fired when the user moves away from the current page. My current page is part of a preferences panel (along with few more pages). In my current page, user can choose the preferences, like the toggle button, a drop down checkbox(multiple) and a radiobutton etc. I don't want to do the database insert each time a user chooses a preference, lets say a toggle or a radiobutton. Instead I want to store all values for all the events, may be a in a array, do a db update when the user moves away from the page. Here I am not using any jQuery.mobile.changePage() to navigate to another pages in the panel. When the user wants to move to another page in the panel, he simply open the panel and clicks on it. $( window ).on('beforeunload' is not firing when the control moves other pages in the preferences panel. In this scenario, how to fire an event when the user moves away from the current page ?

Note : I am using backbone and requires. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which JQM version are you using? Are you using single or multi page model? Is JQM ajax navigation enabled?

Comment: Omar, Thanks for the quick reply. I am using Jquery mobile 1.4. Yes, I am using multipage model. I am not sure about AJAX navigation.

Comment: Multi-page model is all pages in one file/document. In that case, update database on `pageconatainerhide` event based on page's ID. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/